# EF Core reference nulled after SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use following version of EF Core:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6
```

I have following classes:

```cs
public class Garage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Ferrari : Car
{
    public Special Special { get; set; }
}

public class Special
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename=my.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Garage>().ToTable("Garage");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Car");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Ferrari>().ToTable("Ferrari");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Special>().ToTable("Special");
    }
}
```

I have following code:

```cs
await using var context = new MyContext();

await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

var garage = new Garage();

context.Add(garage);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var ferrari = new Ferrari();

garage.Cars.Add(ferrari);

ferrari.Special = new Special();

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}");

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}");
```

Reference to Special is getting nulled. The output is following:

```
Special is null: NO
Special is null: YES
```

You can try yourself: https://github.com/dagid4/EfCoreBug

In database everything is ok. Do you have please any idea how to solve this problem? Or is it just a bug?

It can be related to derived classes. If you move the Special property from Ferrari into Car, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you use context.Add metod the object you are adding is getting marked as Added and it is getting saved when you call save. When you add your object to another object it  is not marked as Added and ignored by context when you call save. And you have to add a GarageId property to the Car class. Otherwise it will never work properly.If only you dont have one garage. But in this case garage class doesn't have any sense at all. And merge Ferrary with the Car class. Otherwise you will need a special table and a lot of problem to make it working.

Try this:

```
var garage = new Garage () ;
var ferrari = new Ferrari();
ferrari.Special = new Special();
garage.Cars.Add(ferrari);

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}")

context.Add(garage);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}");
```

OR

```
var garage = new Garage();

context.Add(garage);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var ferrari = new Ferrari( GarageId=garage.Id);
ferrari.Special = new Special();

context.Add(ferrari);

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}");

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"Special reference is null: {(ferrari.Special == null ? "YES" : "NO")}");
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like it also depends on when SaveChanges is called. Is this behavior intended? Should I call SaveChanges only in some cases and what are the cases?

Comment: In your second example, you are setting GarageId on Ferrari, but this property doesn't exist. Also you have mistakes in both of the examples, it cannot be compiled. Nevermind, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Please show your Garage and Car classes and I will fix the names of  foreign keys. I had to guess you data structure.

Comment: Ok, adding Ferrari into context helped. Thanks! I will test it more and get back. I thought that tracking changes should take care about it. This is why I didn't added other entities.

Comment: Sorry I just checked your link and pls read my last update and add GarageId to the Cars  if only you dont have one garage. But in this case garage class does'n have any sense at all.

Comment: Ok, this is a workaround, thank you very much. But changes tracking should do this automatically. Actually it is doing in TPH but not in TPT. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23180

Answer (score 0):

It is a confirmed bug https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23180. Fix should be available from version 5.0.1 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/23186.

> When propagating the store-generated value to the FK we set the FK store-generated value to null, due to #22603. When accepting the values we overwrite the propagated value with the "store-generated" null. In TPH there are no store-generated values in the Ferrari entry at that point so we don't have to reset them to null, however in TPT the Car part is inserted first and that triggers the creation of the store-generated Sidecar, leading to the situation above.
> — AndriySvyryd